# Fastest approach to deconstructing string

Tags: php, string

I have a `php` string of the form :

```
somename_XXX_someothername_YYY
```

`XXX` & `YYY` = Integers

I want to extract `somename` and `XXX` in an array, such that:

```
array [0] => somename
array [1] => XXX
```

Following is my approach of achieving it:

```
$a = array();
$x = 'stack_312_overflow_213';
$a[] = strstr($x, '_', true);
$a[] = strstr(ltrim(strstr($x, '_', false), '_'), '_', true);
```

I wanted to know if there way any other faster way of doing it as my application will be trimming about 10,000+ strings in this way.

P.S.: I don't know much about speeds, or which `php` functions are the fastest, so thought of posting it here.

Comment: `$arr = explode('_', $string);` then [0] and [1] have your values?

Comment: What's wrong with the native [explode](http://www.php.net/explode) function?

Comment: This isn't what _trim_ means. Trimming is removing characters from the ends of strings, often whitespace.

Comment: @ptokya Please consider deleting your question.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: Its not letting me. I too want to delete it. I've flagged it for mods.

Comment: @ptokya I did the same, thanks!

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: Thanks to you too. Funny, `explode` never occurred to me.

Answer (score 2):

Faster then explode and preg_match:

```
list($word, $num) = sscanf($x, '%[^_]_%d');
```

Also you will have $num as integer already.

If you are willing to use explode, limit it with 3 to speed it up, also you will lose time on casting int on $num if you need it:

```
explode('_', $x, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$arr = explode('_', $str);` and the values in the [0] and [1] spot are the first two values you requested

Answer (score 0):

Below are two ways you can get the information from the string.
Which one of the two is faster? I really have no idea, but you can test it.

This result is from the explode:

```
$result = explode('_', 'somename_XXX_someothername_YYY', 3);

print_r($result);
```

Using a regular expression:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match('/^(.*?)_(.*?)_/', 'somename_XXX_someothername_YYY', $matches);
array_shift($matches); //will remove the first match, which is "somename_XXX_"

print_r($matches);
```

Comment: I'm pretty certain regex is gonna be slower. However, that's not based on any facts.

Comment: **+1 for regexp.** *Don't go cheap on tens of milliseconds.* Write code easy to understand and maintain first, do optimizations and only then do micro-optimizations.

Comment: I'm running a short test (if my php server isn't crashing -_-')

Comment: Explode should be limited, preg_match is too slow.